# Android DP toughts?

Tags: android-layout

Can someone please give me directions on this:
I've got a `ListView`, the adapter got a `LinearLayout` and in this I got four more `LinearLayouts`.

Now I read about dp and it is relative to 160, but when I read different examples this number "160" seems to be different on different screens, so how do I work with dp?

I am used to work with % in this cases.

Now I want my four `LinearLayouts` to be:

- 55dp
- 35pd
- 35pd
- 35pd

Like if the dp was 160!

But as I mentioned above, this dosen't work on all screens.

Can someone tell me how I should work with this? Directions or a good tutorial or similar?

This is what I have tried, and come up with so far:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip" >            

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"    />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

        <Button 
    android:text="Woho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

        <TextView
    android:text="Woho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button 
    android:text="Woho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

        <Button 
    android:text="Woho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

        <TextView
    android:text="Woho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button 
    android:text="Woho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

    </LinearLayout>     
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If i have answered your question, can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the android documentation, 1 DP = 1 pixel on a 160 DPI screen. If the screen is 240 DPI, then 1.5pixel = 1 DP. the size of one DP is independent of underlying hardware resolution but a function of DPI of the screen.

To your layout question, if you assign a fixed width value to your layout, then it will not look good on larger screen sizes.

Better to use layoutweight to distribute the width between those layouts.